# what's causing the gradient to rotate?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I want the make the materials for my blossoms. On the right hand side, you can see the material how it should look like ( with these purple tips on the tip of the leaf), but as you can see on the blossom on the left hand side, the gradient is rotated. I cant figure out what's causing the problem.

[image: cycles material (assigned to both objects)]

[image]

Comment: You will provide easier access to your question if your  provide a clearer screen capture of the nodes. Your screen capture of the nodes is a good idea ... However your capture is not easy to read ... thus some people may choose not to read it.

Comment: Please show an example one successful petal and one unsucessful petal  in edit mode. This may require two screen captures ... which can be composed into one image.   Examine the axis orientation [X,Y,Z]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your orientation of petals is the same for the successful and unsuccessful petals.  In [Edit] mode examine the [XYZ] axis.